# C++ Issue with median function using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function, median

I am having trouble getting this function to work. I am trying to write a median function that takes a user entered array and size, validates that it is correct and then sorts it and displays the median and sorted array. I have tried several different things and no matter what I try I am unable to get this program to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

double median(int n[], int size);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Calculate The Median of an Array" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
    int size, n;
    cout << "Array Size (Maximum is Ten)? ";
    cin >> size;
    if (size > 10 || size < 0) {
        cout << "Invalid size. Please Re-enter." << endl;
    };
    cout << "Array Contents? ";
    cin >> n;
    if ([n] != size) {
        cout << "Invalid Array. Please Re-enter. " << endl;
    };
    median(n, size);
    return 0;
};

double median(int n[], int size) {
     // Allocate an array of the same size and sort it.

    double* dpSorted = new double[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        dpSorted[i] = n[i];
    };

    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (dpSorted[j] > dpSorted[j+1]) {
                double dTemp = dpSorted[j];
                dpSorted[j] = dpSorted[j+1];
                dpSorted[j+1] = dTemp;
            };
        };
    };

    // Middle or average of middle values in the sorted array.
    int median = 0;
    if ((size % 2) == 0) {
        median = (dpSorted[size/2] + dpSorted[(size/2) - 1])/2.0;
    } 
    else {
       median = dpSorted[size/2];
    };

    cout << "Median of the array " << dpSorted << "is " << median << endl;
};
```

I am getting the following errors and I cant figure out how to fix them.

```
34  16  C:\Users\ryanw\Desktop\C++\Labs\Lab 6\main.cpp  [Error] invalid 
conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
```

and

```
18  8   C:\Users\ryanw\Desktop\C++\Labs\Lab 6\main.cpp  [Note] initializing 
argument 1 of 'double median(int*, int)'
```

Comment: Don't use arrays, use std::vector.

Comment: I am very new and I have never used vectors before. I wouldn't know where to start. I am trying to find ways to get what I want using vectors but I am having no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you convert a user entered array into a vector and then convert it back to display?

Comment: Simply don't use arrays at all, don't worry about converting them, do read a good C++ textbook.

Comment: Well I appreciate your input about reading a textbook. I really do. But if I had found an answer that I understood in a textbook then I wouldn't have wasted the time posting this question on here. Thank you.

Comment: OK, which textbooks have you read?

Comment: Starting out with C++ is what I am reading now, C++ for Dummies etc...

Comment: I was hoping for input on my current issue and a push in the right direction. "Use vectors" is an idea that I considered but don't understand yet. I want to learn how to manipulate arrays before jumping in to another subject I don't fully understand

Comment: Isn't it obvious you will not learn C++ from those resources?

Comment: What sources? I asked for some help. That's it. Not criticism. If you don't like the question than please move on and hopefully someone else will assist me.

Comment: `int size` since size can only be positive, consider using an `unsigned` type to eliminate pesky checks for negative values.

Comment: `if ([n] != size)` what do you expect from those square braces?

Comment: Oh okay thank you I will try that. I am trying to compare the size of the entered array with the user entered size to make sure that they match.

Comment: I suspect you are coming in with knowledge of another language and agree that your book is not helping you much. `n` has not been declared to be an array, so you cannot treat it as one. An array in C++ would be defined as `int n[A_CONSTANT_INTEGER];` or as you have done with `double* dpSorted = new double[size];` The second, a dynamic allocation, is not needed here since you know you can't get more than 10 entries, `n` can be `int n[10];`. Reading into `n` requires a loop of `size` iterations and when processing, you only inspect the first `size` elements of `n`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I usually use python and am just now trying to jump into c++ and try to learn how to use it. I am having difficulty switching as I am sure you can tell.

Comment: The languages are very different. This isn't a case of [having to go Full Yoda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4jeREy7Pbc), but it is like learning French from English. The words are similar, but the sentence construction, the mindset, and even the words are different enough that you may accidentally order hemlock when you wanted the fish.

Comment: I am definitely getting that feeling and I like the analogy. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inlining the explanations as comments in the code. Here is the array version. I'm keeping it as close to OP's source as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

double median(int n[], int size);

int main() { // the parameters asre not being used. You can safely leave them out.
    cout << "Calculate The Median of an Array" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
    unsigned int size; // unsigned disallows negative numbers. Lest testing required
    int n[10]; // n is an array of 10 elements
    cout << "Array Size (Maximum is Ten)? ";
    cin >> size;
    while (size > 10) { // repeat until user provides a valid size
        cout << "Invalid size. Please Re-enter." << endl;
        cin >> size;
    };
    // the above loop will be an infinite loop if the user types in a value
    // that cannot be converted into an integer.

    cout << "Array Contents? ";
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cin >> n[index];
    }

    // don't need to test the size. This is ensured by the for loop. Mostly
    // for now we are ignoring the simple problem: "what if the user inputs
    // a value that is not an integer?
    median(n, size);
    return 0;
}// don't need ; after function.

double median(int n[], int size) {
     // Don't need an array of doubles. Ignoring it.

    // assuming the logic here is correct. If it isn't, that's a different
    // topic and another question.
    for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (n[j] > n[j+1]) {
                int dTemp = n[j];
                n[j] = n[j+1];
                n[j+1] = dTemp;
            };
        };
    };

    // Middle or average of middle values in the sorted array.
    double result = 0; //reusing an identifier is a dangerous business. Avoid it.
    if ((size % 2) == 0) {
        result = (n[size/2] + n[(size/2) - 1])/2.0;
    }
    else {
        result = n[size/2];
    };

    cout << "Median of the array is " << result << endl;

    // it's harder to print out an array than I think it should be.
    // Leaving it out for now

    // Other than main, a function with a return type must ALWAYS return.
    return result;
}
```

And with `std::vector` and other library wizardry:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


// using namespace std; generally should avoid this

// moving median up here so forward declaration isn't needed
double median(std::vector<int> &n) { //don't need size. Vector knows how big it is
    std::sort(n.begin(), n.end()); // use built-in sort function

    double result = 0; 
    auto size = n.size();
    if ((size % 2) == 0) {
        result = (n[size/2] + n[(size/2) - 1])/2.0;
    }
    else {
        result = n[size/2];
    };

    // since this function calculates and returns the result, it shouldn't 
    // also print. A function should only do one thing. It make them easier 
    // to debug and more re-usable
    return result;
}


int main() {
    // can chain couts into one
    // endl is more than just a line feed and very expensive. Only use it
    // when you need the message to get out immediately
    std::cout << "Calculate The Median of an Array\n" <<
                 "---------------------------------\n" <<
                 "Array Size (Maximum is Ten)? " << std::endl;
    unsigned int size;
    std::cin >> size;
    while (size > 10) {
        // here we use endle because we want he user to see the message right away
        std::cout << "Invalid size. Please Re-enter:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> size;
    };

    std::vector<int> n(size);

    std::cout << "Array Contents? " << std::endl;
    for (int & val: n) // for all elements in n
    {
        std::cin >> val;
    }

    std::cout << "Median of the array is " << median(n) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate that you explained both. It works now and I have a better understanding of what I was doing wrong. I just need to fix some of the logic as it allows me to enter more than the inputted size but only calculates  the median of the size inputted. I think I want to put an error message disallowing entering more numbers than specified. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an int to `median` here:

```
median(n, size);
```

This line almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does

```
if ([n] != size)
```

I'm slightly concerned that your compiler accepted it as valid syntax.

You will need to change `main` to have a collection of ints for n to pass it to median.

The commenter suggesting using a vector instead of an array is right, raw arrays are *never* the right collection type to use in c++. Note that arrays *don't* occur as parameters in code that interoperates with C, they are treated as *pointers*.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int median(const vector<int> & numbers); // takes a reference to a vector of ints, and ensures the vector isn't changed

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Calculate The Median of some integers" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    vector<int> numbers;
    for(int n; cin >> n;) { numbers.push_back(n); }
    int result = median(numbers);
    cout << "The Median of the numbers is " << result << endl;
    return 0;
};

int median(const vector<int> & numbers)
{
    int size = numbers.size(); // vectors know how many elements they have
    vector<int> copy = numbers; // we copy the vector into a local, that we will modify later, leaving numbers unchanged
    sort(copy.begin(), copy.end()); // sort is a std:: function
    return (size % 2) ? // this is a single expression that chooses from two subexpressions. It is called (the) "ternary operator" (ternary being of three parameters)
        copy[size/2] : // even
        (copy[size/2] + copy[(size/2) - 1])/2; // odd
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. That is a lot of stuff I don't recognize. Thank you for your help. Sorry this may be a dumb question but what are the include statements needed with this code? I added #include <vector> but my compiler doesn't recognize the sort or iterator statements.

Comment: I dislike how you load the `numbers` `vector`. This will require the user to close stdin, something that typically has to be explained to a new programmer and differs from platform to platform. This is an overcomplication when OP's inputs include the size of the `vector`.

Comment: @rcwade93 `std::copy` and `std::sort` require `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: added the required includes

Comment: @user4581301 good point. a loop is actually shorter anyway, changed :)

Comment: Still requires OP to know how to close stdin.

Comment: So I am a still a little confused sorry. It compiles but how do I get user inputs for size and the numbers. And to display the sorted vector in the answer would I just put the copy vector in a print statement like you did with the median. Would that work?

Comment: So what I get from this is that you copy the inputted vector and then sort it using the begin and end statements and then determine whether the length is even or odd? Am I following you? I apologize for the amount of questions but I want to actually understand how the program works .

Comment: Oh damn you changed it. Now I am definitely lost

Comment: @rcwade93 Yes, you are following right. The previous revision used `std::copy` to read from standard input, the `istream_iterators` just mean "treat cin as a sequence of whitespace delimited ints"